# Add custom field data to WooCommerce order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, orders

I have a custom field on my WooCommerce single product. It sends to the cart fine, it displays on checkout fine, it shows in the order in the dashboard fine.

What I am now trying to do is set the value as a custom field in the order page so I am able to amend the text when I need to. For some reason when I submit the form this step isn't working.

The code that i use in my `functions.php`file:

```
// Add the field to the product
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'my_custom_checkout_field');

function my_custom_checkout_field() {
    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h3>'.__('My Field').'</h3>';
    echo  '<label>fill in this field</label> <input type="text" name="my_field_name">';
    echo '</div>';
}

// Store custom field
function save_my_custom_checkout_field( $cart_item_data, $product_id ) {
    if( isset( $_REQUEST['my_field_name'] ) ) {
        $cart_item_data[ 'my_field_name' ] = $_REQUEST['my_field_name'];
        /* below statement make sure every add to cart action as unique line item */
        $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5( microtime().rand() );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'save_my_custom_checkout_field', 10, 2 );

// Render meta on cart and checkout
function render_meta_on_cart_and_checkout( $cart_data, $cart_item = null ) {
    $custom_items = array();
    /* Woo 2.4.2 updates */
    if( !empty( $cart_data ) ) {
        $custom_items = $cart_data;
    }
    if( isset( $cart_item['my_field_name'] ) ) {
        $custom_items[] = array( "name" => 'My Field', "value" => $cart_item['my_field_name'] );
    }
    return $custom_items;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'render_meta_on_cart_and_checkout', 10, 2 );

// Display as order meta
function my_field_order_meta_handler( $item_id, $values, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( isset( $values['my_field_name'] ) ) {
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, "my_field_name", $values['my_field_name'] );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'my_field_order_meta_handler', 1, 3 );

/** THIS IS WHERE I'M STUCK **/

add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');
function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    global $woocommerce;

    // Check if set, if its not set add an error. This one is only requite for companies
    if ($_POST['billing_company'])
        if (!$_POST['my_field_name']) 
            $woocommerce->add_error( __('Please enter your XXX.') );
}
// Update the user meta with field value
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_user_meta');
function my_custom_checkout_field_update_user_meta( $user_id ) {
    if ($user_id && $_POST['my_field_name']) update_user_meta( $user_id, 'my_field_name', esc_attr($_POST['my_field_name']) );
}

// Update the order meta with field value

add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta');
function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ($_POST['my_field_name']) update_post_meta( $order_id, 'My Field', esc_attr($_POST['my_field_name']));
}
```

Screenshot of what currently happens:

[image: Screenshot of what currently happens]

---

---

What I would like to happen:

[image: what I would like to happen]

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> **Updated:** compatibility with Woocommerce version 3+

You have missing the function to display this custom field value on the order edit page:

```
/**
 * Display field value on the order edit page
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta( $order ){
    $order_id = method_exists( $order, 'get_id' ) ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('My Field Name').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order_id, 'my_field_name', true ) . '</p>';
}
```

On the reference link below, you have all original wooThemes functional working code snippets. It's an excellent fully functional tutorial.

Reference: [Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters][1]

---

> **Edit: Get a custom label displayed with your custom field value in Order item meta**
>
> To get a custom label like "**MY field name**" with your custom field value *(in order items meta)* instead of a slug like **my_field_name**, refer to this treads:
>
> - [Saving a product custom field and displaying it in cart page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43681589/saving-a-product-custom-field-and-displaying-it-in-cart-page/43687373#43687373)
> - [Displaying product custom fields values in the order once processed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42086412/displaying-product-custom-fields-values-in-the-order-once-processed/42087408#42087408)
> - [Adding user custom field value to order items details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981493/adding-user-custom-field-value-to-order-items-details/41988701#41988701)

Comment: Thank you, this has definitely put me on the right track, the last thing I am struggling with is the checkout processing stage. Because my field is actually inserted on the product page, how do I process the checkout with this field without it being a required field as shown in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this still is relevant, I have tried to do this with code, unfortunately, I got stuck in the way. I have tried this [woocommerce checkout field editor plugin](https://woocommerce.com/products/conditional-checkout-fields-for-woocommerce/), which did well to add custom field data to woocomemrce order.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33712553)