# Displaying product custom fields values in the order once processed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, orders

On woocommerce, I am using the code below to render some product custom fields, on cart and on checkout:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'rendering_meta_field_on_cart_and_checkout', 10, 2 );

function rendering_meta_field_on_cart_and_checkout( $cart_data, $cart_item ) {
    $custom_items = array();

    if( !empty( $cart_data ) ) {
        $custom_items = $cart_data;
    }
    if( isset( $cart_item['wccpf_enter_product_id'] ) ) {

        $diamond = $cart_item['wccpf_enter_product_id'];

        $pacolor = get_the_terms($diamond, 'pa_color');
        foreach ( $pacolor  as $pacolor  ) {
           $color= $pacolor ->name;
        }


        $custom_items[] = array( "name" => "color", "value" => $color);
    }
    return $custom_items;
}
```

How can I display that custom product fields wccpf_enter_product_id' value in orders?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom function hooked in woocommerce_add_order_item_meta action hook to achieve this.

> **You will need first to add an attribute in your products to get a "readable clean label" for your custom field value that is going to appear as order items meta data.**
>
> For that you have to create an attribute first and then set it in your product with any value (as you will replace this value in the code below).
>
> See [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981493/adding-user-custom-field-value-to-order-items-details/41988701#41988701) some more explanations about that process…
>
> You will have to replace in my code the **`'custom_field_key'`** by your specific custom key that you will find on **`wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta`** MySQL table for the corresponding item ID for your specific Order ID. 
>   To find the corresponding **`item ID`** for the order, you can search in **`wp_woocommerce_order_items`** MySQL table with the Order ID…
>
> You will have also to set your correct attribute slug instead of **`'pa_your_attribute'`** to display in your orders the correct label text for this custom field value. 
>   *(see below other similar answers references).*

So your code will be something like this:

```
// ADD THE INFORMATION AS META DATA SO THAT IT CAN BE SEEN AS PART OF THE ORDER
add_action('woocommerce_add_order_item_meta','add_and_update_values_to_order_item_meta', 1, 3 );
function add_and_update_values_to_order_item_meta( $item_id, $item_values, $item_key ) {

    // Getting your custom product ID value from order item meta
    $custom_value = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'custom_field_key', true );

    // Here you update the attribute value set in your simple product
    wc_update_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'pa_your_attribute', $custom_value );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This should work

---

**Related answers:**

- [Adding user custom field value to order items details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981493/adding-user-custom-field-value-to-order-items-details/41988701#41988701)
- [Add custom Product data dynamically as item meta data on the Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41971376/add-custom-product-data-dynamically-as-item-meta-data-on-the-order/41971727#41971727)
- [Displaying custom product data in Order items view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41970803/displaying-custom-product-data-in-order-items-view/41971459#41971459)